# Commerce-Marketplace : Members tab in store's page doesn't show up

Tags: 7, commerce

After this clean install :

- Drupal 7.28
- Commerce 7.x-1.9
- Commerce-Marketplace 7.x-1.0-beta2 (same issue with current dev version)
- ECK 7.x-2.0-rc3+15-dev

I create a new store but can't see the "Members" tab as seen on the demo site (I also tried the direct URL "commerce_store/store/{ID}/people", no error but I stay on store page).

[Here is a screenshot](https://drupal.org/files/issues/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202014-06-11%20%C3%A0%2018.02.46.png)

[And the demo site](http://cmp.bazarayan.com/)

Do I miss a step to activate the store members management tab/pages ?

Thanks for your help or direction to solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem resolved after this update : https://www.drupal.org/node/2284457#comment-8962135